# Disable Activiti Spring REST API Basic Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, activiti

We already have security configuration present in our application and we would like to use the same for security Activiti's rest services as well. I have tried to search around the internet but couldn't find a direct way to disable activiti's authentication configuration.

Spring version: 4.x
Aciviti version: 5.x

`web.xml` config:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer</listener-class>
</listener>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable Activit REST API basic authentication by adding below code to any configuration class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

If you are not using Spring boot, you can follow [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.7/topics/rest_endpoints_security_overrides.html) blog.

Comment: May be this blog can help you...http://docs.alfresco.com/process-services1.7/topics/rest_endpoints_security_overrides.html

Comment: Tried.. getting exception in package.

Comment: is this correct : http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/**").permitAll();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164305/discussion-between-learn-hadoop-and-yogi).

Comment: This doesn't work with activiti 7 and spring boot 2.6.6. Any solutions?