# Disable Spring Security in Activiti 7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, activiti

I am new to spring security. I am writing an application that uses activiti 7 and spring boot 2.6.7. I have added a class that allows anonymous requests (shown below). I have a rest controller that exposes a POST api. I still get an HTTP 403 error when calling the POST api. My goal is to disable spring security for the rest apis and the execution of the activiti process. I tried the solution [noted on this stackoverflow link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542799/disable-activiti-spring-rest-api-basic-authentication) but it seems old, hence doesn't work. Any solutions?

Thanks.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Activiti7ApplicationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //....other methods
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```